# c# read from many files and write just part of them into new file

Tags: c#

I've try to read many files one by one and write just part of them into new file.
I am new in c#, can someone give me some idea, how to do it.

Here is the code, but in this way only record all files in one main file. I want to get some information with substring from all file, and write this information to main file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace ConsoleApp2
    {
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string path = @"C:\Users\Name\Desktop\Files\";
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            using (var output = File.Create(path + "output.txt"))
            {
                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    using (var data = File.OpenRead(file))
                    {
                        data.CopyTo(output);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at System.IO.File

Comment: Please, provide details: which files (binary, text), what are the *parts* (10 bytes from each? top line from every text one)? Examples will be very helpful. Don't forget to show your code even if it is incomplete, throws exception etc.

Comment: Use StreamReader and StreamWriter.  You will have to parse the read files and depending on the format of the file depends on how the parsing is done.  There isn't a single method that works well with all different types of files.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. At the moment this question is fairly vague - we don't know what you've already tried, or where you're stuck. Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ and edit your question to be more specific.

Comment: What you have tried? Lot of stuff available to read & write the directories and files. Do something yourself then come here with the code in which you might have problem.

Comment: The files are text files. Top Line from text file, but just part of top line. Something with substring i think.

Comment: Again, please *edit the question* to give all the details, including what you've tried already.

Comment: yes, it will most likely be something with substring; or regex; or split; or any of a dozen different things; without meaningful input/output, all we can say is "yes, that is probably possible"

Comment: Can someone look the code and give me some help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this for example if you want to use `Substring`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string path = @"C:\Users\Name\Desktop\Files\";

            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

            //Reads the first lines
            var firstLines = files.Select(f => File.ReadLines(f).First());

            //Cuts from the fifth character and then five characters long
            //Writes the result to the file output.txt
            File.WriteAllLines(path + "\\output.txt", firstLines.Select(l => l.Substring(5, 5)));
        }
    }
}
```

But you can also use other string manipulation methods like `Replace`.